# WP-CLI doesn't replace sitename

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-cli

I am trying replace the site url via `WP-CLI` the command bellow:

```
wp search-replace "https://oldUrl" "http://newUrl" --allow-root --all-tables --verbose
```

However I am getting in the console:

```
+----------------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+------+
| Table                                  | Column                  | Replacements | Type |
+----------------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+------+
| wp_post                                |                         | skipped      |      |
| wp_user                                |                         | skipped      |      |
| wp_postmeta                            |                         | skipped      |      |
| wp_usermeta                            |                         | skipped      |      |
| .........                              |                         | skipped      |      |
```

What I missed?

Comment: That looks correct. Is your old site `https`? Try doing the search-replace without the HTTP protocol `//oldUrl` `//newUrl`

Comment: @disinfor I tried without the HTTP protocol, unfortunately not working

Comment: Found this: https://kellenmace.com/wp-cli-search-replace-tables-skipped/ Might be useful in your case. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. `One of the keys in each database table has to be marked as the primary key, or else WP-CLI will skip over it and output skipped as shown above`. Thanks `@disinfor` very help me. Always to check the tables in database.